# InaccessibleObjectException when configuring the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm currently learning Spring and I'm trying to run a hibernate example that I've taken out of a book called "Pro Spring 5" (p 380), but I'm getting an IllegalStateException caused by an InaccessibleObjectException when initializing the GenericApplicationContext with AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.

Here is the configuration class:

```
package com.panfleto.prueba.probando.hibernate.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan (basePackages = {"com.panfleto.prueba.probando.hibernate"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {
     
     @Bean
     public DataSource dataSource() {
            DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
            dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("**************");
            dataSourceBuilder.url("**************");
            dataSourceBuilder.username("**************");
            dataSourceBuilder.password("**************");
            return dataSourceBuilder.build();
     }
     
     private Properties hibernateProperties() {
         Properties hibernateProp = new Properties();
         hibernateProp.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
         hibernateProp.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
         hibernateProp.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);
         hibernateProp.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
         hibernateProp.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
         hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 10);
         hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 50);
         return hibernateProp;
     }

     @Bean
     public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws IOException {
         LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
         sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
         sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.panfleto.prueba.probando.hibernate.modelado");
         sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
         sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
         return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
     }

     @Bean
     public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IOException {
         return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
     }
}
```

The main class:

```
package com.panfleto.prueba.probando.hibernate;

import java.util.List;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext;
import com.panfleto.prueba.probando.hibernate.config.AppConfig;
import com.panfleto.prueba.probando.hibernate.dao.CantanteDAO;
import com.panfleto.prueba.probando.hibernate.modelado.Cantante;

public class App 
{
     private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
     
     public static void main(String... args) {
         try
         {
             GenericApplicationContext ctx =
                     new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
             CantanteDAO cantanteDao = ctx.getBean(CantanteDAO.class);                       
             listSingers(cantanteDao.findAll());
             ctx.close();    
         } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
     
     private static void listSingers(List<Cantante> cantantes) {
         logger.info(" ---- Listing singers:");
         for (Cantante cantante: cantantes) {
             logger.info(cantante.toString());
         }
     }

}
```

The pom file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
      <groupId>com.panfleto.prueba</groupId>
      <artifactId>probando.hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
      <name>probando.hibernate</name>
      <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
      <url>http://www.example.com</url>
    
      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
      </properties>
    
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
          <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>  
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>8.0.15</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.11</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.15</version>
    </dependency>
        
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
          <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
    
      </dependencies>
    
      <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
          <plugins>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
      </build>
    </project>
```

And the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.panfleto.prueba.probando.hibernate.config.AppConfig
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:414)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88)
    at com.panfleto.prueba.probando.hibernate.App.main(App.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:403)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7a3d45bd
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7a3d45bd
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: For starters your dependencies are a bit of a mess. YOu are mixing Spring 5.0, 5.3 and whatever the spring boot version you are using is pulling in. As you are using 5.0 that is only working up to java 8, you are using a newer java version. I would strongly suggest to either follow the book (which you aren't) or to use Spring Boot properly (to manage your dependencies).

Comment: That was the problem, thanks! Yeah, my whole project is a completely mess, I should try to organize everything.